# How to manually install package to a project that uses cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I was hoping to use a library that is on Hackage. But it turns out that the maintainer of the package has abandoned the library for some time and now it's not compiling due to minor problems. Now that I fixed the problems, what is the best way to link it with my cabal project until my PR is merged into the upstream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install it like "cabal install ..." would install it, try this:

1. Use "cabal get pkgname-X.Y.Z" to get the source from Hackage; it places the source in the directory `pkgname-X.Y.Z`
2. `cd` into the source directory and apply your patches
3. Run `cabal install`

There are other options if you are using `stack` or cabal sandboxes.

Comment: I am using a cabal sandbox.